# Как добавить новую строку в существующий QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, table, qtablewidget

Моё приложение (образовательные цели). Когда пользователь открывает приложение, QTableWidged заполняется  данными загруженными из .xml файла. Когда пользователь хочет добавить номер в QTableWidget, то он столкнется с проблемой связанной стам фактом что я работал через setRowCount (весьма топорно) в текущем значении,после  ввода QTableWidged  выведет только одну сроку.

Как я могу решить эту проблему?

Вопрос является переводом статьи  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957943/how-to-add-new-row-to-existing-qtablewidget

*С добавлением комментариев переводчика, в связи с тем что сам столкнулся с такими же проблемами.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример добавления строки в таблицу (`QTableWidget`) через цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    table->setRowCount(table->rowCount() + 1);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: я по торопился и выпустил вопрос без ответа )))

Comment: Зато, ответ у вас обширный и не пересекается с моим :)

Answer (score 1):

Что - то подобное должно работать :

```
tableWidget->insertRow( tableWidget->rowCount() );
```

Эта команда добавит строку в конец вашей таблицы. Вы можете использовать функцию insertRow() для того чтобы вставлять новые строки в середину таблицы.

*Сам использую именно этот метод (вот код):*

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()); 
ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(person_ID_map[ID])));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(per_ID_count_map[ID])));
```

*Создание новой строки, а с самой информацией в строках работаю через вектора(set, map)*

---

Что бы раскрыть ответ @Chris-a (*самый верхний*) :
Если вы хотите добавить данные в таблицу (т.д. Push_back и заполнить новую строку):

```
tableWidget->insertRow ( tableWidget->rowCount() );
tableWidget->setItem   ( tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 
                         yourColumn, 
                         new QTableWidgetItem(string));
```

// повторите для большего количества столбцов

Если вы заранее знаете количество строк и столбцов:

```
ui->tableWidget->clear();
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(numRows);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(numColumns);
for (auto r=0; r<numRows; r++)
     for (auto c=0; c<numColumns; c++)
          tableWidget->setItem( r, c, new QTableWidgetItem(stringData(r,c)));
```